# Replicating google earth plugin navigation functionality with external buttons

Tags: javascript, html, google-earth-plugin

With a Google Earth javascript plugin embedded in an HTML page, would it be possible to replicate the Google Earth Navigation using a series of HTML links below the Google Earth plugin?

[image: Google Earth Navigation]

I would just need the zoom button functionality, without the slider,The 4 main move directions (up, down, left, right) and up and down for camera tilt of the Look buttons.

Rotate can remain at North always. Its not needed.

A sample of buttons.

```
<div id="map3d" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<h3>Look</h3>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="up">up</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="right">right</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="down">down</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="left">left</a>
<h3>Move</h3>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="north">north</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="east">east</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="west">west</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="south">south</a>
<h3>Zoom</h3>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="zoomIn">Zoom In</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" id="zoomOut">Zoom Out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible you just change the camera parameters.

See: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control

Basically, you get the current view, and either change it to the new spot, or adjust it (ie. every time the button is clicked, move X degrees or something).

Code from the link above copied here in case it changes at a later date:

```
// Get the current view.
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Add 25 degrees to the current latitude and longitude values.
lookAt.setLatitude(lookAt.getLatitude() + 25.0);
lookAt.setLongitude(lookAt.getLongitude() + 25.0);

// Update the view in Google Earth.
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```